# Programatically populating ValidValues property of ReportParameters in .NET for SSRS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to populate an SSRS parameter's ValidValues property at run-time without writing custom stored procedures. The issue is that the available values for a certain parameter change depending on a user's security level. I'd like to keep the logic for it in the code rather than in stored procedures. Is there a way to populated ValidValues for ReportParameters in .NET for SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating a data set (either a select statement or sp) to pull the possible values?  you can then set the parameter to use the data set.

Comment: This I can do, but then the logic will be in the database and not in the code. This is something I wanted to avoid. My fall back option is to write some sprocs or UDFs + sprocs to attain the desired effect.

Comment: are the parameters going to be static or dynamic?  if they're static you can just set up your own values by hand.